# Error when I try deploy application to tomcat7 server

Tags: maven, deployment, tomcat7

I am trying deploy a web application to tomcat7 via eclipse luna, but I am getting this error:

```
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Floja

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Floja

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Floja

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Floja

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.936 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-15T22:10:04-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project loja: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I also try deploy to tomcat8, but I get this same error.

In my pom.xml, I have this configuration related to this operation:

```
  <build>
    <finalName>loja</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.2</version>
           <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/loja</path>
                <username>user001</username>
                <password>123</password>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Anyone knows what's happening here?

**UPDATE**

I try deploy the application with the command `mvn:tomcat7 deploy -X` and the output was that:

```
[INFO] Retrying request
[DEBUG] Reopening the direct connection.
[DEBUG] Connecting to localhost:8080
[DEBUG] Attempt 4 to execute request
[DEBUG] Sending request: PUT /manager/text/deploy?path=%2Floja HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG]  >> "PUT /manager/text/deploy?path=%2Floja HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "User-Agent: Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin/2.2[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "Content-Length: 18783041[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "Authorization: Basic dXNlcjAwMToxMjM=[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG]  >> "[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] >> PUT /manager/text/deploy?path=%2Floja HTTP/1.1
[DEBUG] >> User-Agent: Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin/2.2
[DEBUG] >> Content-Length: 18783041
[DEBUG] >> Host: localhost:8080
[DEBUG] >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[DEBUG] >> Authorization: Basic dXNlcjAwMToxMjM=
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Floja
...
[DEBUG] Connection 0.0.0.0:53183<->127.0.0.1:8080 closed
[DEBUG] Closing the connection.
[DEBUG] Connection 0.0.0.0:53183<->127.0.0.1:8080 closed
[DEBUG] Connection 0.0.0.0:53183<->127.0.0.1:8080 shut down
[DEBUG] Connection 0.0.0.0:53183<->127.0.0.1:8080 closed
[DEBUG] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 5]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.271 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-16T08:11:09-03:00
[DEBUG] Connection manager is shutting down
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Connection manager shut down
```

Comment: The `url` is rigth?, normally is `http://localhost:8080/manager/`

Comment: @AVolpe yes. it's right. I was deploying without problem with the eclipse kepler, when I update to luna the error started.

Comment: Try to run **mvn tomcat7:..... -X** to get more information about the problem

Comment: @Skizzo Ok, I try this way and the message was added to the question (see update). it has a stacktrace too, but i don't have space to post. the last one was `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

Comment: I believe the url should be `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` and remove the forward slash in path

Comment: @KarthikPrasad No, this url open the graphical version of the manager (via browser). the url used here is for access via command line. I use the url `localhost:8080/manager/text` without problem in version kepler of the eclipse. When i update to luna, don't work anymore.

Comment: Does anybody has a solution for this ? Off course debug mode doesn't say more.

Answer (score 21):

By default Tomcat has a max upload size of 50MB. (I.e max size of `WAR` file)

If you require larger file, try increasing `max-file-size` and `max-request-size` within the tomcat `web.xml`. Note: those values are both stored in bytes.

Edit `.../webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml`. (Ensure the file sizes are larger than the `war` file your trying to upload). I.e if you require 80MB WAR,

```
  <max-file-size>82914560</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>82914560</max-request-size>
```

Then restart apache tomcat.

https://octopus.com/blog/tomcat-manager-deployment

Answer (score 19):

Ok, I had the same issue with tomcat7.

```
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2iplover

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2iplover

[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request:         Connection reset
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2iplover
```

I could not get it to work with

```
mvn tomcat7:redeploy
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26037783/1596891).

My WAR wasn't very large, just 4MB.

### Here was the root problem and solution

It is important that your `tomcat-users.xml` has the correct roles setup. I ONLY had the role `manager` setup. Adding `manager-script` seems important and completely solved my problem.

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if anybody solved this issue. I have found a workaround in my case: use of redeploy instead of deploy works fine.

The issue may perhaps be related to memory issue or read/write access isn't it ?

Comment: It worked for me : Sumits-MacBook-Pro:TestService eSumit$ mvn tomcat7:redeploy -X, Received : [INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK

Answer (score 10):

What's the size of your war? maybe it is because the size too large. By default, tomcat manager only allow less then 50MB size war. also try mvn tomcat7:redeploy instead of deploy.

[See here how to increase the war size limit](http://maxrohde.com/2011/04/27/large-war-file-cannot-be-deployed-in-tomcat-7/)

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue and solved it by running the maven goal

> tomcat7:redeploy

instead of

> tomcat7:deploy

It worked for both tomcat7 and tomcat8, and my war file was always below 50mb.

Answer (score 2):

Check ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>tomcat-manager</id>
      <username>user001</username>
      <password>123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue and in my case the problem was a cunfigured context path not starting with /.
Fixing the context path "myapp" to "/myapp" solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Occasionally problems

If sometimes the redeployment fails, sometimes succeed, a increase of the logging might show a DOS protection.

Edit the `/conf/logging.properties` and add the line

```
org.apache.catalina.level = FINEST
```

At the end of the file. Might show this output:

```
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke Security checking request PUT /manager/text/deploy
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass loadClass(org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet, false)
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass   Delegating to parent classloader1 java.net.URLClassLoader@568db2f2
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass   Loading class from parent
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Status interface]' against PUT /text/deploy --> false
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Text Manager interface (for scripts)]' against PUT /text/deploy --> true
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HTML Manager interface (for humans)]' against PUT /text/deploy --> false
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[JMX Proxy interface]' against PUT /text/deploy --> false
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Status interface]' against PUT /text/deploy --> false
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Text Manager interface (for scripts)]' against PUT /text/deploy --> true
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HTML Manager interface (for humans)]' against PUT /text/deploy --> false
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[JMX Proxy interface]' against PUT /text/deploy --> false
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasUserDataPermission   User data constraint has no restrictions
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling authenticate()
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate Attempting to authenticate user [admin] with realm [org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm]
FINER [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.authenticate Username [admin] NOT successfully authenticated
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate Failed to authenticate user [admin] with realm [org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm]
WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts 
     An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user [admin]
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Failed authenticate() test
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=401, location=/WEB-INF/jsp/401.jsp]
FINER [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate   Returning non-STM instance
FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward  Disabling the response for further output
```

(in this logging the user who made the attempt to upload has the username `admin`)

As you see in this output the user `admin` is locked:

```
WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts 
  An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user [admin]
```

Look into the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/realm.html#LockOut_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm) and inside the `server.xml` and you will find a

```
   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

### Use unforseeable username

To remove the line is a bad idea, change the username for redeployment to a different, more unforeseeable name like `deploy355547511` to not get locked.

Comment: How do I change the username from `admin` to something else, like `deploy` when deploying the WAR files to Tomcat?

Comment: @tom_mai78101 Yes, your question is absolutly justified! You will find the `conf/tomcat-users.xml` file. By default this file is empty because of security reasons. If you read the comments in the `tomcat-users.xml` carefully you will become aware of a combination of username, password and role and you will ask another question: **What is the role the manager-app uses for deployments?**! The solution to this question is part of the manager-app's `web.xml`.

Comment: I know what to do now, and I got my specific problem fixed. I modified `conf/tomcat-users.xml` but I still get `admin` as the username, hinting to me that there may be more to this. I wasn't sure, until I realized this is a Maven 2 Eclipse (m2e) specific settings where Maven would use the default, `admin`, unless you tell m2e to use a different username and password when deploying. I had to add a `settings.xml` inside `/home/username/.m2/` directory.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 You do not have to use `settings.xml`, you can override the deploy-username by `-Dtomcat.username=xxx`.

Answer (score 2):

(Re-)deploy with the Maven tomcat plugin failed for me too with a connection reset on the client and 403 status code in the `localhost_access.log` on Tomcat 8.5.30.

This Tomcat version's manager app has a `RemoteAddrValve` configured by default, restricting access to the /manager/* path to localhost. See `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml`.

It helped to [turn on the logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48967599/1528287) to find [the solution to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286101/1528287).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps , But in My case .
tomcat7 plugin was picking server details from the maven conf settings.xml instead room .m2\settings.xml .
Adding server information in that file Resolved my Issue .

Answer (score 0):

In my case on my AWS amazon instance the reason was:

**The Disk Space Was *FULL*** note 99% on my EC2 spot instance

Am using jenkins using this command normally

```
 mvn clean tomcat7:redeploy -Ddeploy.password=xxxAG1
 -Ddeploy.username=admin -Ddeploy.context=/v1 -Ddeploy.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/text
```

[image]

**Just Free that space and it worked with me.**

The Error i had is

```
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
[INFO] Retrying request


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 53.914 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-10T08:38:28+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 47M/371M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) on project XXXX-app: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

**Hint** use this command 
to track down what is eating your space from ( [command is from stackoverflow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135824/what-is-the-tomcat-installation-directory) )
sudo du -x   -d1 -h /