# Tomcat deployment using maven plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy my webapp to tomcat7 on Amazon AWS EC2 instance using maven from my local system, but I am continuously getting this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project EnrollItWeb: Cannot invoke Tomcat mana
ger: Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) o
n project EnrollItWeb: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(TomcatManager.java:880)
        at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:742)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:705)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:388)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
        ... 23 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I have added the plugin in pom.xml

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://{my-ip}:{my-port}/manager/html</url>
                    <server>{server-name}</server>
                    <path>/{context-path}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and corresponding server setting in $MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml

```
    <server>
      <id>{server-name}</id>
      <username>{username}</username>
      <password>{password}</password>
    </server>
```

I am having Ubuntu instance at AWS with tomcat installed at root.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28706706/3124333

Comment: No, i tried that but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`<url>http://{my-ip}:{my-port}/manager/text</url>` instead of `<url>http://{my-ip}:{my-port}/manager/html</url>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in pom.xml this lines:

```
<username>YourUserName</username>
<password>YourPassword</password>
```

inside configuration block, like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://{my-ip}:{my-port}/manager/html</url>
        <server>{server-name}</server>
        <path>/{context-path}</path>
        <username>YourUserName</username>
        <password>YourPassword</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```